# Dynamically change number of variables in NSStringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

Let's say I have string like this:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@",variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4,variable5];
```

and if `variable2` is `nil` I don't want that in my string, like this:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",variable1,variable3,variable4,variable5];
```

**Question**

Is there any way to do this without having a lot of if-statements?

Comment: You could have an array consist of those variables and iterate them while checking if thats nil or not and then append them into a mutable string.

Comment: @AdilSoomro thanks! It will be half your solution and half trojanfoe's :)

Comment: you welcome, well if you taking the other half as suggesting about having mutable string, that point I already suggested. ;)

Comment: Err, you cannot create an array with `nil` elements, so that's a "no go".

Comment: @trojanfoe oh, that part I missed. thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, and instead create an `NSMutableString` and append strings as necessary:

```
NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
if (variable1)
    [s appendString:variable1];
if (variable2)
    [s appendString:variable2];
if (variable3)
    [s appendString:variable3];
if (variable4)
    [s appendString:variable4];
if (variable5)
    [s appendString:variable5];
```

(sorry I missed your point about "not having lots of `if` statements", however I don't think it can be avoided).

Comment: Nice one. That was too easy :). Thanks a bunch!

Comment: About the if's. This way makes it a lot easier than having if's with NSStringWithFormat so it's perfectly fine.

Comment: I need to look into NSMutableString more - this is outstanding.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the compacted ternary operator to replace a null with an empty string. Using a slightly abridged version of your example:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",variable1 ?: @"",variable2 ?: @""];
```